# Postgresql - Function get row as parameter - How to acces to a column of this row?

Tags: postgresql, user-defined-functions

I have a function that must get as paramater a row of a table employee and returnd the age of the employee passed as parameter:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getAge(employe employee) RETURNS int AS $$
begin
  return employe.age;
END; $$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

I am trying to call the function like

```
select * from getAge('(1, Alexander, 34, null)' );
```

But it doesn't work. I am expecting that the function returns 34. How should I call the function properly?

Comment: You shouldn't be storing the age in a column to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your employee table looks somewhat like this:

```
knayak=# \d employee
              Table "public.employee"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default
--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 id     | integer |           |          |
 name   | text    |           |          |
 age    | integer |           |          |
 col4   | text    |           |          |
```

Simply call it as

```
select getAge ('(1,Alexander,34,null)');
 getage
--------
     34
```

Or use an table alias from a query as the input.

```
select getage(emp)
from employee as emp
where e.id = 1;
```

`select * from func()` is used for a `SET/TABLE` returning functions.

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=bd66d4e82df5cdf90e0a6bb0e6b70e1f)